# Pantalla completa en layout vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy implementnado Vuetify en un proyecto, pero no logro hacer para que los elementos de pagina abarquen toda la pantalla
[image: asi es como se ve]

y este es el codigo del template

```
v-container grid-list-lg text-lg-left>
            <v-layout align-center justify-start/>
            </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

y quisiera que abarcara toda la pantalla, sin los margenes de los lados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza fluid al momento de declarar el contenedor:

```
<v-container fluid grid-list-lg text-lg-left>
        <v-layout align-center justify-start/>
        </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)